# non i.i.d Normal Sample

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, normal-distribution

I have N non-iid Normal($\mu$, 1) samples, with correlation matrix of $\rho$ for all off-diagonal entries. How do I calculated or estimated $\mu$? What is the test statstics?

correlation matrix is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&\rho&\rho\\ \rho&1&\rho\\ \rho&\rho&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I thing the biggest unknown is what do you want to test.

Comment: Do you need to estimate $\rho$ or do you assume it known?